# Iterating over tables with nested <th> tags with BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

The following code iterates over a table with nested `th` headings.

The decision has been made to just go with the main heading and ignore sub-headings, but nested structure still needs to be preserved to differentiate between the two.

The logic to traverse the rows and sub-rows correctly to preserve the nested structure and avoid data duplication took some time to figure out. Furthermore, the code must be revised (to accommodate sub-sub-rows... etc.) when the nested levels increase.

Just wondering if there is a more efficient and fool-proof way to do this?

```py
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = Session()

with session.get('http://cht.a-hospital.com/w/穴位') as resp:
    resp.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')

    table = soup.select('table:-soup-contains("位置區分") table')[0]
    rows = table.find_all("tr")

    data_list = []

    for row in rows:
        if row.th and row.td:
            heading = row.th.text

            if row.tr:
                sub_rows = row.find_all("tr")

                for sub_row in sub_rows:
                    if sub_row.th:
                        rows.remove(sub_row)

                        if sub_row.ul:
                            data = sub_row.ul.text
                            data_list.append((heading, data))  # ignore sub-heading

            if row.ul and not row.tr:
                data = row.ul.text
                data_list.append((heading, data))


print(*data_list, sep="\n")
```

## Table to be Scraped:

```html
<table cellspacing="0" class="nowraplinks collapsible uncollapsed navbox-inner" style="border-spacing:0;background:transparent;color:inherit;;">
<tr>
<th class="navbox-title" colspan="3" scope="col" style=";">
<div class="" style="font-size:110%;"><a href="/w/%E4%B8%AD%E5%8C%BB" title="中醫">中醫百科</a> - 按位置區分的<strong class="selflink">人體穴位</strong>列表</div>
</th>
</tr>
<tr style="height:2px;">
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="navbox-group" scope="row" style=";;">頭部</th>
<td class="navbox-list navbox-odd hlist" style="text-align:left;border-left-width:2px;border-left-style:solid;width:100%;padding:0px;;;">
<div style="padding:0em 0.25em"></div>
<table cellspacing="0" class="nowraplinks navbox-subgroup" style="border-spacing:0;;;;">
<tr>
<th class="navbox-group" scope="row" style=";padding-left:0em;padding-right:0em;;">
<div style="padding:0em 0.75em;">正面</div>
</th>
<td class="navbox-list navbox-odd" style="text-align:left;border-left-width:2px;border-left-style:solid;width:100%;padding:0px;;;">
<div style="padding:0em 0.25em">
<ul>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%A4%B4%E7%BB%B4%E7%A9%B4" title="頭維穴">頭維穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%8F%91%E9%99%85%E7%A9%B4" title="髮際穴">髮際穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E9%98%B3%E7%99%BD%E7%A9%B4" title="陽白穴">陽白穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%8D%B0%E5%A0%82%E7%A9%B4" title="印堂穴">印堂穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E6%94%92%E7%AB%B9%E7%A9%B4" title="攢竹穴">攢竹穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E7%9D%9B%E6%98%8E%E7%A9%B4" title="睛明穴">睛明穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E6%89%BF%E6%B3%A3%E7%A9%B4" title="承泣穴">承泣穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%9B%9B%E7%99%BD%E7%A9%B4" title="四白穴">四白穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%BF%8E%E9%A6%99%E7%A9%B4" title="迎香穴">迎香穴</a></li>
<li><a class="mw-redirect" href="/w/%E6%B0%B4%E6%B2%9F%E7%A9%B4" title="水溝穴">水溝穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E7%9E%B3%E5%AD%90%E9%AB%8E%E7%A9%B4" title="瞳子髎穴">瞳子髎穴</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:2px">
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="navbox-group" scope="row" style=";padding-left:0em;padding-right:0em;;">
<div style="padding:0em 0.75em;">背面</div>
</th>
<td class="navbox-list navbox-even" style="text-align:left;border-left-width:2px;border-left-style:solid;width:100%;padding:0px;;;">
<div style="padding:0em 0.25em">
<ul>
<li><a href="/w/%E7%99%BE%E4%BC%9A%E7%A9%B4" title="百會穴">百會穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%90%8E%E9%A1%B6%E7%A9%B4" title="後頂穴">後頂穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E9%A3%8E%E5%BA%9C%E7%A9%B4" title="風府穴">風府穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%93%91%E9%97%A8%E7%A9%B4" title="啞門穴">啞門穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%AE%8C%E9%AA%A8%E7%A9%B4" title="完骨穴">完骨穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E9%A3%8E%E6%B1%A0%E7%A9%B4" title="風池穴">風池穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%A4%A9%E6%9F%B1%E7%A9%B4" title="天柱穴">天柱穴</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:2px">
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="navbox-group" scope="row" style=";padding-left:0em;padding-right:0em;;">
<div style="padding:0em 0.75em;">背面</div>
</th>
<td class="navbox-list navbox-odd" style="text-align:left;border-left-width:2px;border-left-style:solid;width:100%;padding:0px;;;">
<div style="padding:0em 0.25em">
<ul>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%A4%AA%E9%98%B3%E7%A9%B4" title="太陽穴">太陽穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E4%B8%8B%E5%85%B3%E7%A9%B4" title="下關穴">下關穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E4%B8%8A%E5%85%B3%E7%A9%B4" title="上關穴">上關穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%80%B3%E9%97%A8%E7%A9%B4" title="耳門穴">耳門穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%90%AC%E5%AE%AB%E7%A9%B4" title="聽宮穴">聽宮穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E7%BF%B3%E9%A3%8E%E7%A9%B4" title="翳風穴">翳風穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E9%A2%8A%E8%BD%A6%E7%A9%B4" title="頰車穴">頰車穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%A4%A7%E8%BF%8E%E7%A9%B4" title="大迎穴">大迎穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E4%BA%BA%E8%BF%8E%E7%A9%B4" title="人迎穴">人迎穴</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<td class="navbox-image" rowspan="11" style="width:0%;padding:0px 0px 0px 2px;">
<div><a href="/w/%E4%BA%BA%E4%BD%93%E7%A9%B4%E4%BD%8D%E5%9B%BE" title="人體穴位圖"><img alt="Xue full.gif" height="147" src="http://p.ayxbk.com/images/thumb/2/26/Xue_full.gif/200px-Xue_full.gif" width="200"/></a></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:2px">
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="navbox-group" scope="row" style=";;">腹部<br/>
胸部</th>
<td class="navbox-list navbox-odd hlist" style="text-align:left;border-left-width:2px;border-left-style:solid;width:100%;padding:0px;;;">
<div style="padding:0em 0.25em">
<ul>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%A4%A9%E7%AA%81%E7%A9%B4" title="天突穴">天突穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%86%BB%E4%B8%AD%E7%A9%B4" title="膻中穴">膻中穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E9%B8%A0%E5%B0%BE%E7%A9%B4" title="鳩尾穴">鳩尾穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%B7%A8%E9%98%99%E7%A9%B4" title="巨闕穴">巨闕穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E4%B8%AD%E8%84%98%E7%A9%B4" title="中脘穴">中脘穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E6%B0%B4%E5%88%86%E7%A9%B4" title="水分穴">水分穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E6%B0%94%E6%B5%B7%E7%A9%B4" title="氣海穴">氣海穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%85%B3%E5%85%83%E7%A9%B4" title="關元穴">關元穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E4%B8%AD%E6%9E%81%E7%A9%B4" title="中極穴">中極穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E6%B0%94%E8%88%8D%E7%A9%B4" title="氣舍穴">氣舍穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E4%BF%9E%E5%BA%9C%E7%A9%B4" title="俞府穴">俞府穴</a></li>
<li><a class="mw-redirect" href="/w/%E6%88%96%E4%B8%AD%E7%A9%B4" title="或中穴">或中穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E6%9C%9F%E9%97%A8%E7%A9%B4" title="期門穴">期門穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%88%E7%A9%B4" title="日月穴">日月穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%A4%A9%E6%9E%A2%E7%A9%B4" title="天樞穴">天樞穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E6%B0%94%E7%A9%B4" title="氣穴">氣穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%A4%A7%E5%B7%A8%E7%A9%B4" title="大巨穴">大巨穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%A4%A7%E8%B5%AB%E7%A9%B4" title="大赫穴">大赫穴</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:2px">
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="navbox-group" scope="row" style=";;">背部</th>
<td class="navbox-list navbox-odd hlist" style="text-align:left;border-left-width:2px;border-left-style:solid;width:100%;padding:0px;;;">
<div style="padding:0em 0.25em">
<ul>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%A4%A7%E6%A4%8E%E7%A9%B4" title="大椎穴">大椎穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E9%99%B6%E9%81%93%E7%A9%B4" title="陶道穴">陶道穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%BA%AB%E6%9F%B1%E7%A9%B4" title="身柱穴">身柱穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E7%A5%9E%E9%81%93%E7%A9%B4" title="神道穴">神道穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%87%B3%E9%98%B3%E7%A9%B4" title="至陽穴">至陽穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%84%8A%E4%B8%AD%E7%A9%B4" title="脊中穴">脊中穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E6%B2%BB%E5%96%98%E7%A9%B4" title="治喘穴">治喘穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%82%A9%E4%BA%95%E7%A9%B4" title="肩井穴">肩井穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E6%9B%B2%E5%9E%A3%E7%A9%B4" title="曲垣穴">曲垣穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%A4%A9%E5%AE%97%E7%A9%B4" title="天宗穴">天宗穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%91%BD%E9%97%A8%E7%A9%B4" title="命門穴">命門穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%85%B0%E4%BF%9E%E7%A9%B4" title="腰俞穴">腰俞穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%85%B0%E9%98%B3%E5%85%B3%E7%A9%B4" title="腰陽關穴">腰陽關穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E4%B8%8A%E4%BB%99%E7%82%B9%E7%A9%B4" title="上仙點穴">上仙點穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%85%AD%E5%8D%8E%E7%81%B8%E7%A9%B4" title="六華灸穴">六華灸穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E9%A3%8E%E9%97%A8%E7%A9%B4" title="風門穴">風門穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%82%BA%E4%BF%9E%E7%A9%B4" title="肺俞穴">肺俞穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%BF%83%E4%BF%9E%E7%A9%B4" title="心俞穴">心俞穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%86%88%E4%BF%9E%E7%A9%B4" title="膈俞穴">膈俞穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%82%9D%E4%BF%9E%E7%A9%B4" title="肝俞穴">肝俞穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%86%8F%E8%82%93%E7%A9%B4" title="膏肓穴">膏肓穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%BF%97%E5%AE%A4%E7%A9%B4" title="志室穴">志室穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%82%A9%E5%A4%96%E4%BF%9E%E7%A9%B4" title="肩外俞穴">肩外俞穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%8E%A5%E9%98%B4%E4%BF%9E%E7%A9%B4" title="厥陰俞穴">厥陰俞穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E4%B8%89%E7%84%A6%E4%BF%9E%E7%A9%B4" title="三焦俞穴">三焦俞穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%A4%A7%E8%82%A0%E4%BF%9E%E7%A9%B4" title="大腸俞穴">大腸俞穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%85%B3%E5%85%83%E4%BF%9E%E7%A9%B4" title="關元俞穴">關元俞穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%B0%8F%E8%82%A0%E4%BF%9E%E7%A9%B4" title="小腸俞穴">小腸俞穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%86%80%E8%83%B1%E4%BF%9E%E7%A9%B4" title="膀胱俞穴">膀胱俞穴</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:2px">
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="navbox-group" scope="row" style=";;">上肢</th>
<td class="navbox-list navbox-odd hlist" style="text-align:left;border-left-width:2px;border-left-style:solid;width:100%;padding:0px;;;">
<div style="padding:0em 0.25em">
<ul>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%86%85%E5%85%B3%E7%A9%B4" title="內關穴">內關穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%A4%96%E5%85%B3%E7%A9%B4" title="外關穴">外關穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E6%9B%B2%E6%B1%A0%E7%A9%B4" title="曲池穴">曲池穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%B0%BA%E6%B3%BD%E7%A9%B4" title="尺澤穴">尺澤穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E6%B2%BB%E7%97%92%E7%A9%B4" title="治癢穴">治癢穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%AD%94%E6%9C%80%E7%A9%B4" title="孔最穴">孔最穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%88%97%E7%BC%BA%E7%A9%B4" title="列缺穴">列缺穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E9%98%B3%E6%B1%A0%E7%A9%B4" title="陽池穴">陽池穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E7%A5%9E%E9%97%A8%E7%A9%B4" title="神門穴">神門穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%90%88%E8%B0%B7%E7%A9%B4" title="合谷穴">合谷穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E4%B8%AD%E6%B8%9A%E7%A9%B4" title="中渚穴">中渚穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%B0%91%E5%86%B2%E7%A9%B4" title="少沖穴">少沖穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%90%BD%E6%9E%95%E7%A9%B4" title="落枕穴">落枕穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E6%8C%87%E9%97%B4%E7%A9%B4" title="指間穴">指間穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%A4%AA%E6%B8%8A%E7%A9%B4" title="太淵穴">太淵穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%8F%A3%E5%86%85%E7%82%B9" title="口內點">口內點</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%83%83%E8%82%A0%E7%82%B9" title="胃腸點">胃腸點</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E6%89%8B%E4%B8%89%E9%87%8C%E7%A9%B4" title="手三里穴">手三里穴</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:2px">
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="navbox-group" scope="row" style=";;">下肢</th>
<td class="navbox-list navbox-odd hlist" style="text-align:left;border-left-width:2px;border-left-style:solid;width:100%;padding:0px;;;">
<div style="padding:0em 0.25em">
<ul>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%86%9D%E7%9C%BC%E7%A9%B4" title="膝眼穴">膝眼穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E6%A2%81%E4%B8%98%E7%A9%B4" title="梁丘穴">梁丘穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%A4%8D%E6%BA%9C%E7%A9%B4" title="復溜穴">復溜穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E9%98%B4%E8%B0%B7%E7%A9%B4" title="陰谷穴">陰谷穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%A1%80%E6%B5%B7%E7%A9%B4" title="血海穴">血海穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E6%89%BF%E5%B1%B1%E7%A9%B4" title="承山穴">承山穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%A7%A3%E6%BA%AA%E7%A9%B4" title="解溪穴">解溪穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%A7%94%E4%B8%AD%E7%A9%B4" title="委中穴">委中穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%B6%B3%E4%B8%89%E9%87%8C%E7%A9%B4" title="足三里穴">足三里穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E9%98%B3%E9%99%B5%E6%B3%89%E7%A9%B4" title="陽陵泉穴">陽陵泉穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E9%98%B4%E9%99%B5%E6%B3%89%E7%A9%B4" title="陰陵泉穴">陰陵泉穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E4%B8%89%E9%98%B4%E4%BA%A4%E7%A9%B4" title="三陰交穴">三陰交穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E7%99%BE%E9%87%8C%E7%A9%B4" title="百里穴">百里穴</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:2px">
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="navbox-group" scope="row" style=";;">足部</th>
<td class="navbox-list navbox-odd hlist" style="text-align:left;border-left-width:2px;border-left-style:solid;width:100%;padding:0px;;;">
<div style="padding:0em 0.25em">
<ul>
<li><a href="/w/%E6%B6%8C%E6%B3%89%E7%A9%B4" title="湧泉穴">湧泉穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%A4%A7%E6%95%A6%E7%A9%B4" title="大敦穴">大敦穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%A4%AA%E5%86%B2%E7%A9%B4" title="太沖穴">太沖穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%A4%AA%E7%99%BD%E7%A9%B4" title="太白穴">太白穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%A4%AA%E6%BA%AA%E7%A9%B4" title="太溪穴">太溪穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E7%94%B3%E8%84%89%E7%A9%B4" title="申脈穴">申脈穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E4%B8%98%E5%A2%9F%E7%A9%B4" title="丘墟穴">丘墟穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E6%98%86%E4%BB%91%E7%A9%B4" title="崑崙穴">崑崙穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%B6%B3%E4%B8%B4%E6%B3%A3%E7%A9%B4" title="足臨泣穴">足臨泣穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E8%A1%8C%E9%97%B4%E7%A9%B4" title="行間穴">行間穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E9%87%8C%E5%86%85%E5%BA%AD%E7%A9%B4" title="里內庭穴">里內庭穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E4%B8%8B%E7%97%A2%E7%A9%B4" title="下痢穴">下痢穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E5%8E%89%E5%85%91%E7%A9%B4" title="厲兌穴">厲兌穴</a></li>
<li><a href="/w/%E7%AC%AC%E4%B8%89%E5%8E%89%E5%85%91%E7%A9%B4" title="第三厲兌穴">第三厲兌穴</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The example HTML you have posted is not well-formed. There are tag terminations (`tr`, `table`) with no matching tag start. If the markup in the wild has a section that is well-formed, I encourage you to post it, having reformatted it to have non-zero indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [is there] a more efficient and fool-proof way to do this?

So long as you don't scrape, yes, there is a more efficient and robust method.

Notice that this is a [WikiMedia instance](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page). As such, the content you're looking at is not defined in HTML; it's defined in WikiMedia markup (just as Wikipedia is).

Further notice that the page you're scraping:

[http://cht.a-hospital.com/w/穴位#.E6.8C.89.E4.BD.8D.E7.BD.AE.E5.88.86.E7.B1.BB.E7.9A.84.E5.B8.B8.E7.94.A8.E7.A9.B4.E4.BD.8D.E5.88.97.E8.A1.A8](http://cht.a-hospital.com/w/%E7%A9%B4%E4%BD%8D#.E6.8C.89.E4.BD.8D.E7.BD.AE.E5.88.86.E7.B1.BB.E7.9A.84.E5.B8.B8.E7.94.A8.E7.A9.B4.E4.BD.8D.E5.88.97.E8.A1.A8)

is not actually the page you care about. You only care about this template:

[http://cht.a-hospital.com/w/Template:导航板-人体穴位分布](http://cht.a-hospital.com/w/Template:%E5%AF%BC%E8%88%AA%E6%9D%BF-%E4%BA%BA%E4%BD%93%E7%A9%B4%E4%BD%8D%E5%88%86%E5%B8%83)

A quirk of this MediaWiki instance is that its direct `action=parse&prop=wikitext` support seems to be broken. So instead, just pull from the raw link:

[http://cht.a-hospital.com/index.php?title=Template:导航板-人体穴位分布&action=raw](http://cht.a-hospital.com/index.php?title=Template:%E5%AF%BC%E8%88%AA%E6%9D%BF-%E4%BA%BA%E4%BD%93%E7%A9%B4%E4%BD%8D%E5%88%86%E5%B8%83&action=raw)

Comment: How do you parse this string `'{{Navbox\n |name = 导航板-人体穴位分布\n |title = [[中医|中医百科]] - 按位置区分的[[穴位|人体穴位]]列表\n |image = [[File:Xue full.gif|link=人体穴位图|200px|]]\n |listclass  = hlist \n |state = uncollapsed\n |group1 = 头部\n |list1  =  {{Navbox subgroup\n\n| group1 = 正面\n|  list1 = \n*[[头维穴]]\n*[[发际穴]]\n*[[阳白穴]]\n*[[印堂穴]]\n*[[攒竹穴]]\n*[[睛明穴]]\n*[[承泣穴]]\n*[[四白穴]]\n*[[迎香穴]]\n*[[水沟穴]]\n*[[瞳子髎穴]]\n| group2 = 背面\n|  list2 = \n*[[百会穴]]\n*[[后顶穴]]\n*[[风府穴]]\n*[[哑门穴]]\n*[[完骨穴]]\n*[[风池穴]]\n*[[天柱穴]]\n...}}<noinclude>[[分类:导航板]]</noinclude>' into python data structures?
`

Comment: Either parse it yourself using in-built string operations, or use something like `wikitextparser` or `mediawiki-parser` from pip.